# Disable roll-out animation for NSOutlineView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Is there a way to stop the roll-out animation for an NSOutlineView. By 'roll-out' I mean the animation that happens when an item is expanded/collapsed, and the children slide down/up.

Comment: I'm so glad you asked this.  I can't stand this animation and am shocked that Apple declared it a standard and gave us no clear off switch.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a subclass of NSOutlineView and suppress animation:

```
-(void) expandItem:(id)item expandChildren:(BOOL)expandChildren
{
    [NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];
    [[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setDuration:0.0];

    [super expandItem:item expandChildren:expandChildren];

    [NSAnimationContext endGrouping];
}
```

Other methods are:

```
– expandItem:
– expandItem:expandChildren:
– collapseItem:
– collapseItem:collapseChildren:
```

Comment: This is wonderful.  Is there anyway you can conceive of to disable this animation in the Finder, in Xcode, all through the Mac OS through an NSUserDefaults?

Comment: I did find this on my travels: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45339/how-to-disable-finder-triangle-reveal-animation-in-10-7-lion. Don't know if helps you.

Comment: Heh.  My comments are all over that post.  No working answer yet.

Comment: Note that because the expandItem: and collapseItem: methods are documented as calling the more verbose counterparts, you only need to override expandItem:expandChildren: and collapseItem:collapseChildren: